# how to check if a file is selected using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, file

In php this is how you would check if a file is selected:

```
$_FILES['item']['size']>0
```

what about in JavaScript?

I need to know because I have a function that will only work if a file is selected.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-49531485 says:

> value of type DOMString
>     When the type attribute of the element has the value "text", "**file**" or "password", this represents the current contents of the corresponding form control, in an interactive user agent.

```
<html>
  <head><title>...</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function foo() {
        var f = document.getElementById("f1");
        alert( ""==f.value ? "nothing selected" : "file selected");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div>
        <input id ="f1" type="file" name="x" />
      </div>
    </form>
    <button onclick="foo()">click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here (https://jsfiddle.net/mitma/ra6fv8kc/) a revised proposed demo, but I don't understand a strange behavior that I'm trying to solve, that brought me here: if I execute the code from a mobile device, the multiple selection turns out to be ONE, while from the computer no ... There seems to be a different trigger between the (multiple) selection made with the mouse and the one made with the touch on a mobile device... I opened a topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56476753/2149425

Answer (score 8):

I use this javascript:

```
var file_selected = false;
function showNoFile() {
    if(!file_selected) { alert('No file selected!'); } // or anything else
}
```

with this html for the file button:

```
<input type='file' onchange="file_selected = true;" ...>
....
<input type='submit' onclick='showNoFile();'>
```

hope that helps!

Comment: I think this is the best answer. If you want to do like an AJAX request when someone chooses a file the `onchange` function is what you want. If you simply use `onclick` it fires once the choose file dialog is opened, but before a file is chosen.

Comment: it doesn't work in chrome... if you choose a file then you choose no file again the file_selected remains true which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

So lets say you have some html form and you have a custom file upload input:

```
<label for="imageUploadButton">
<span class="btn" style="padding-left: 10px;">Click here for uploading a new picture</span>
</label> 
<input type="file" name="avatar_picture" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png" id="imageUploadButton" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;">
```

And you want to check the filename of the file the user has chosen/selected:

Using jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     $("input:file").change(function (){
       var fileName = $(this).val();
       alert(fileName); //Do with the filename whatever you want
     });
  });
</script>
```

@https://stackoverflow.com/a/5670938/2979938

For those using requireJS:

```
$("input:file").change(function () {
  var fileName = $(this).val();
  alert(fileName); //Do with the filename whatever you want
});
```