# PHP Check if someone chose a file

Tags: php

Can someone show me some example code on how i would check to see if someone picked a file in the file input field as i only want to display a message if they have.

Cheers,

Comment: This is well covered in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if you want it to do it while they were using the form you would need to use javascript
you can see it be done here

[how to check if a file is selected using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1417462/260640)

you want a php solution one way can also bee seen in the same topic

this is for multiply files

```
foreach($_FILES['item']['size'] as $k=>$v){
    if($v>0)
         //Do something
}
```

try that

Comment: Ohhh one more thing .... If i have multiple file input fields and they are labelled item[] ... How would i redo the above source code to fit that scenario

Comment: Thats exactly what i was after ... Thanks a bunch Breezer :)