# How to check if one of the file input types has value?

Tags: jquery

I have many of these input types:

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload">
```

And when the submit button is clicked, I want to check via JS if one these fields are not empty (in other words, there is at least one file is uploaded).

Here's my code which doesn't work:

```
$('#upload-button').live('click', function () {
  var has_selected_file = $('input[type=file]').val();

  if (has_selected_file) {
    /* do something here */
  }
  else {
    alert("No file selected");
  }
});
```

This always alerts no file selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to findout input element with a value, and check the length

```
$('#upload-button').live('click', function () {
    var has_selected_file = $('input[type=file]').filter(function(){
        return $.trim(this.value) != ''
    }).length  > 0 ;

    if (has_selected_file) {
        /* do something here */
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, care to explain what is the use of filter and the return part too?

Comment: `filter` is a js native function which executes the specified function on every member of the object/array. Here you iterate over the collection of input[file] tags and returns an array of all elements with a selected file. If this array is non-zero in length, `has_selected_file` is true .. hence `do something`

Answer (score 1):

you could just do:

```
var has_selected_file = $.trim( $('input[type=file]').val());

if (has_selected_file != "") {
    /* do something here */
}
else {
    alert("No file selected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to handle `change` instead of `click`?

It seems working here:

[jQuery - Detecting if a file has been selected in the file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670769/jquery-detecting-if-a-file-has-been-selected-in-the-file-input)