# check if a file is loaded to <input type="file">

Tags: jquery

Everything is in the title: how can I check if a file is loaded to `<input type="file">` ?

```
<input type="file" id="document-file" />
<input type="submit" id="document-send" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#document-send').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var files = $("#document-file");
        console.log(files.length);
    }
</script>
```

`files.length` always returns me `1` even if no file is loaded.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5670938/3509874

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `files` property of the element, not the jQuery object:

```
var files = $("#document-file")[0].files;
```

Comment: yeah! it works, but what is the element in the position `0` ?

Comment: The DOM element is at position `0` - it is essentially doing a `getElementById`

Answer (score 3):

You could just try to read if the input has a value:

```
if(document.getElementById("document-file").value != ""){
    // do stuff here
}
```

If it does, theres a file, if its empty there isn't. It's backwards compatible with browsers that don't support fileReaders.

Comment: Best answer I found to use vanilla javascript to see if there is something loaded into the file input of a form.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the `.val()` of the input, then check the `.length` of that value.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p7WNC/)**

Here is how I did it in fiddle.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var files = $("#document-file").val();
    if(files.length > 0){
         $('body').append(files + '<br />');
    } else {
         $('body').append('No File <br />');
    }
});
```

I hope this helps!