# Is there a way to check if any of the file inputs have been filled?

Tags: jquery

I have a form with multiple input file types. I want to check if any of the inputs have a file selected. I have tried `$('.multi').val()` but this is not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/hbdyresq/

```js
$('.bt').on('click', function() {
  var filesSelected = $('.multi').val();
  console.log(filesSelected)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<button class="bt" type="button">button</button>
```

Comment: You can use one input for multiple files: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp

Comment: If you read the docs for .val() you will see it picks the first input from the jQuery collection. So you will need to loop in some manner to check them all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check if a file is loaded to <input type="file">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017185/check-if-a-file-is-loaded-to-input-type-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if *any* of the file inputs have a file selected you can use `filter()` to retrieve only those where the `files.length` is not zero:

```js
$('.bt').on('click', function() {
  var filesSelected = $('.multi').filter((i, el) => el.files.length).length != 0;      
  console.log(filesSelected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<button class="bt" type="button">button</button>
```