# Onsubmit event after javascript form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, file

I have an upload file form, and i try to upload the file when it's selected,so i tried something like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onsubmit="return
UploadFile(this);">                                 
<input id="upfile" type="file" onchange="this.form.submit();"/>
</form>
```

The form.submit() works , but of course i need to do some validation on submit,so i tried to run a function:

```
 function UploadFile(file){
       alert('Bleah');
       return false;
    }
```

On normal circumstances it should return false, and the form shouldn't reload the page,but this doesn't happens.

If i add a submit input into the form, it works as expected:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onsubmit="return
UploadFile(this);">
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">                                  
<input id="upfile" type="file"/>
</form>
```

Can anyone explain me what is wrong please?

Comment: try `onchange="return this.form.submit();"`

Comment: @JaromandaX , is not working ... same behavior

Comment: How would you plan to submit the form?

Comment: If you need some validations of submit then why do you submit form once file is selected ?

Comment: @RayonDabre , because i don't want a submit button

Comment: Which are those fields which need to be validated ?

Comment: Try this. `<input id="upfile" type="file" onchange="return
UploadFile(this.form);"/>`

Comment: @RayonDabre , the file , of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function UploadFile(file) {
  if (file.value === '') {
    alert("Invalid File");
  } else {
    alert('Form will be submitted now!');
    document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="myForm">
  <input id="upfile" name="upfile" type="file" onchange="UploadFile(this);" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

To upload the file when it's selected, you must call `UploadFile()` function on the `input` change, not on the `form` change tag. If you submit on input change, the page gets reloaded.
So, you'd better use something like this:

```
$('#upfile').onchange(function(){
   if(UploadFile(this.parent('form'))){
   this.parent('form').submit();
}
})
```

And you won't need `onchange` and `onsubmit` inside the tags any more.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<form id="formname" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="test.html">
<input id="upfile" type="file" onchange="sendForm()"/>
</form>

<script>
  function sendForm() {
    var field = document.getElementById("upfile");
    if (field) {
      console.log("the is a file and the form will be sent");
      document.forms["formname"].submit();
    }

  }

</script>
```

OLD--
I dont understand, how would you like to submit the form without a submit button? or at least, handle the submission in javascript "object.addEventListener("keydown", myScript);"

--
ok, I read it once again and I understand the question

You need to handle this on javascript and detect the selection of the file. Look at this thread:

[how to check if a file is selected using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417462/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-selected-using-javascript)

Comment: well , there is an onchange event with this.form.submit() , shouldn't that work as a submit button ?

Comment: consider that if you need validation, then that is the answer, you validate the field has a value != '' and then you can submit it

Comment: I would try it in plain javascript

Comment: what i try to achieve is a faster and smoother way of uploading a file, as soon as the file was selected,it should upload the file(submit the form) , run a validation onsubmit , and return a boolean value , depending on that the file can be uploaded or not , with the thread you gave me, i can't do this...

Comment: @Cynthia Sanchez, Just to correct you, `field` will always return DOM object of `id="upfile"` so it will never be false. You need to check the value of the input. To clarify, try ~console.log(field)` before if condition..