# How to detect multiple files selection with touch screen on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, touch-event, multipleselection

I need to count the number of selected files during a multiple selection by clicking on a `input type="file"` element of a form. I'm writing the code on my laptop and everything is working fine with this code:

```js
function counter() {
  var inputUploader = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]'),
    chosenFiles = inputUploader.files,
    filesCount = chosenFiles.length > 1 ? chosenFiles.length : chosenFiles.length;
  alert(filesCount);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input id="inputUploader" type="file" name="x" multiple />
  </div>
</form>
<button onclick="counter()">click</button>
```

But trying to test the code on a mobile device ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mitma/ra6fv8kc/)), I incontered the bug: if I execute the code from a mobile device, the multiple selection turns out to be ***ONE*** (number), while from the computer no... There seems to be a different trigger between the ***(multiple) selection*** made with the ***mouse*** and the one made with the ***touch*** on a mobile device.

Cheers and thank you

**#Edit:**

I also noticed that, if you visit the demo from the *VIA mobile browser* (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mark.via.gp), the multiple selection is not available, while if you browse from *Firefox mobile* it is possible, but as mentioned the selection seems to be UNIQUE